Noises from Sequential Bipolar Montage

If Fp1 and F3 forms a differential V+, V- and
F3 and C3 forms another differential V+, V- and
C3 and P3 forms another differential V+, and V- and
P3 and O1 forms another differential V+, and V-
What noises could be introduced to say the F3 and C3 channel with them connecting to another pair (as illustrated above)?
